# Mobx-react console warning related observer

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Im getting below warning when I tried to run my react code, I have run 'npm run eject' and update package.js for making decorator work in react,  it is working fine but Im getting below warning in console

> [MobX] You haven't configured observer batching which might result in
>   unexpected behavior in some cases. See more at
>   https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite/#observer-batching

```
import {  observable, computed, action, when  } from 'mobx';

class TodoStore {
    @observable todos = [];
    @observable filter = "";
}
```

above is my code, Im new to mobx and react

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some edge cases in regards to update order of parent-child components.
try adding this to the file.

```js
import 'mobx-react-lite/batchingForReactDom'
```